# Faster algorithm for finding primitive roots

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, primitive

I'm trying to find prime roots with this algorithm:

```
std::vector<unsigned long long> Keyexchange::primroot(unsigned long long val) {

    std::vector<unsigned long long> res;

    for (unsigned long long i = 2; i<val - 1; i++) {

        unsigned long long start = 1;
        bool flag = 1;

        for (unsigned long long j = 0; j<val / 2; j++) {
            start = (start * i) % val;
            if (start % val == 1) {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            res.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

It works great but it is very very slow.
I want to calculate the primitive roots of big numbers like 1073741789. It would be the best if there is a possibility to set a range because I am calculating the whole set right now.

**So basicely I am looking for a way [code snipet would be great] to generate about 100.000 of the biggest primitive roots out of that given big number.**

I know that it is much faster with the Eulersche φ-function but I have no idea how to implement it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's feasible with φ-function if the input number is semi-prime and you know its (two) prime factors. Is that the case with your input numbers?

Answer (score 8):

First, if you pick a random integer from 2 to p-1 then it has a decent chance of being a primitive root. So you pick a random integer (or you start with 2), check it, and if it fails, you pick the next one etc.

To check that x is a primitive root: It means that x^(p-1) = 1 (modulo p), but no smaller power of p is. Take for example p = 31, p-1 = 30 = 2 x 3 x 5. If p is not a primitive root, then one of x^(30/2), x^(30/3) and x^(30/5) must be 1 (modulo p).

Factor p-1 in its prime factors, calculate x^((p-1)/f) (modulo p) for every prime factor f, and x is a primitive root if none of the results is 1.

Of course x^y (modulo p) needs to be calculated with repeated squaring/multiplying. For example to calculate x^10 you would calculate x^2, x^4, x^5, x^10 in that order.

Once you found a primitive root g, g^k is a primitive root if gcd (k, p-1) = 1. But it would be a rare situation where you care for more than one primitive root.

Answer (score 1):

If the input number is [semi-prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) and you have its (two) prime factors at hand, then you can use this:

```
vector<uint64> Roots(uint64 p,uint64 q)
{
    vector<uint64> roots;

    uint64 zstar = p*q;
    for (uint64 y=1; y<zstar; y++)
    {
        if (GCD(zstar,y) == 1 && InQR(y,p,q))
        {
            uint64 yp = PowMod(y,(p+1)/4,p);
            uint64 yq = PowMod(y,(q+1)/4,q);
            uint64 r1 = Map(0+yp,0+yq,p,q);
            uint64 r2 = Map(0+yp,q-yq,p,q);
            uint64 r3 = Map(p-yp,0+yq,p,q);
            uint64 r4 = Map(p-yp,q-yq,p,q);
            roots.push_back(r1);
            roots.push_back(r2);
            roots.push_back(r3);
            roots.push_back(r4);
        }
    }

    return roots;
}
```

Here are the auxiliary functions:

```
uint64 GCD(uint64 a,uint64 b)
{
    uint64 c = a%b;
    if (c == 0)
        return b;
    return GCD(b,c);
}

uint64 PowMod(uint64 x,uint64 e,uint64 n)
{
    uint64 y = 1;
    while (e > 0)
    {
        if (e & 1)
            y = (y*x)%n;
        x = (x*x)%n;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return y;
}

bool InQR(uint64 y,uint64 p)
{
    return PowMod(y,(p-1)/2,p) == 1;
}

bool InQR(uint64 y,uint64 p,uint64 q)
{
    return InQR(y,p) && InQR(y,q);
}

uint64 Map(uint64 u,uint64 v,uint64 p,uint64 q)
{
    uint64 a = q*Inverse(p,q);
    uint64 b = p*Inverse(q,p);
    return (u*a+v*b)%(p*q);
}

uint64 Inverse(uint64 n,uint64 a)
{
    int64  x1 = 1;
    int64  x2 = 0;
    int64  y1 = 0;
    int64  y2 = 1;
    uint64 r1 = n;
    uint64 r2 = a;

    while (r2 != 0)
    {
        uint64 r3 = r1%r2;
        uint64 q3 = r1/r2;
        int64  x3 = x1-q3*x2;
        int64  y3 = y1-q3*y2;

        x1 = x2;
        x2 = x3;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = y3;
        r1 = r2;
        r2 = r3;
    }

    return (uint64)(y1>0? y1:y1+n);
}
```